# MySQL dúvida em Select

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela de chats em `mysql`, nela esta o registo de conversas entre utilizadores.

Os campos são.

```
id, id_from, id_to, message
```

Example (My Data in DB):

```
1, 50, 10, 'Hello'
2, 10, 50, 'Nice?'
3, 50, 10, 'Yeah, And you?'
4, 10, 50, 'Me too'
5, 1, 20, 'Hello'
6, 20, 1, 'Nice?'
7, 1, 20, 'Yeah, And you?'
8, 20, 1, 'Me too'
8, 50, 1, 'Hey.....'
9, 1, 50, 'Whats???'
10, 50, 1, ': )'
11, 1, 50, 'LOL'

[user]
id
name

id 50 = Paul
id 1= Samuel
id 20= Donald
id 10 = Max
```

O que eu preciso é via `select`, retornar a ultima conversa que ocorreu entre as pessoas.

Por exemplo, no meu `select`, eu quero saber as duas ultimas conversas (mostrando apenas a ultima mensagem de cada conversa) que o `id 50` teve `Paul`.

Como poderia fazer isso via `MySQL`?

O resultado seria assim:

```
4, 10, 50, 'Me too'
11, 1, 50, 'LOL'
```

Comment: A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

Levando em conta que o nome da sua tabela seria `chat` a `query` ficaria mais ou menos parecida com o seguinte:

```
SELECT c2.id,
       c2.id_from,
       c2.id_to,
       c2.message
  FROM (SELECT MAX(c1.id) as id
          FROM chats c1
         WHERE c1.id_from = 50 -- Paul
         GROUP BY c1.id_from, c1.id_to) ids
  INNER JOIN chats c2 ON c2.id = ids.id;
```

A subquery irá agrupar os `ids` agrupado por código do usuário de origem e destino. Levei em consideração também que o id é sequencial.